# How many architecture styles there are?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices, soa, system-design

I've heard about such architecture styles like 'Layered', 'SOA' and 'Microservices'? Which else do exist?

In order to understand all possible variants and the difference between them i would like to systemize all of them in my head.

Comment: Check out Dr Milan Milanović's blog: https://medium.com/@techworldwithmilan/most-common-software-architecture-styles-86881d779683

Answer (score 1):

There are so many architectural patterns such as:

- Layered Pattern
- Client-Server Pattern
- Event-Driven Pattern
- Microkernel Pattern
- Microservices Pattern
- Broker Pattern
- Event-Bus Pattern
- Pipe-Filter Pattern
- Blackboard Pattern
- Service-Oriented Architecture (SOA)
- Monolithic Architecture:
- Space-Based Architecture
- Peer-to-Peer Architecture
- Hybrid Architecture

They have some pros and cons. [Read more about them in this great article.](https://www.turing.com/blog/software-architecture-patterns-types/#Layered_Pattern)